# Get arbitrary number of arguments from scanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, scanf

Hey I was wondering if anyone knew how to solve this problem.  I want to grab user input and from that preform some operations off that.  Right now I am getting a segfault on a scanf line and can't figure out why.  After that I am trying to concatenate the two arrays together and help with that would be great also.

```
char command[1000];
char firstName[1000];
char lastName[1000];
char month[1000];
char day[1000];

while( strcmp("quit", &command[0]) != 0 ){
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Please enter next command: ");
    scanf("%s", command);                    // <--- This is tested and working

    if(strcmp(&command[0], "quit") == 0){
        break;
    }

    else if(strcmp(&command[0], "empty") == 0){
        empty();
    }
    else if(strcmp(&command[0], "append") == 0){
        printf("--------->1");

        scanf("%s %s %s %s", firstName, lastName, month, day); //<--- This line :(

        printf("--------->2");  // <---- This never prints
        char fullName[2001];
        char birthday[2001];

        malloc(strlen(firstName) + 1);
        strcpy(firstName, fullName);

        malloc(strlen(lastName) + 1);
        strcpy(lastName, fullName);
        printf("%s", fullName);
```

From the terminal:

```
gregs-mbp:desktop GregR$ ./blist
Please enter next command: append greg r jan 02
Segmentation fault: 11
gregs-mbp:desktop GregR$ ./blist
Please enter next command: append     
--------->1greg r jan 02
Segmentation fault: 11
gregs-mbp:desktop GregR$ 
gregs-mbp:desktop GregR$ ./bList
Please enter next command: quit
All done
```

Comment: What is the actual input from the user?

Comment: it would be something like: 

Please enter next command: append greg r jan 02

Comment: your code doesnt give segmentation fault. can you give the input for which you get segmentation fault with output.

Comment: please add the input to the question

Comment: Also won't work for append Jeff Nequit Jan 02

Comment: There are other errors and unusual calls to `malloc` in your code but there is nothing wrong with the `scanf` line.

Comment: @Greg In `strcpy(firstName, fullName);`, you are using `fullName` before you initialize it, and this could cause segment fault. And `malloc(strlen(firstName) + 1);` will allocate some memeory and throw it away, what is your intention with this statement?

Comment: Are you sure it is "<--- This line" that is having problems? There are major problems later in the code.  If you are using the existence of "--->2" as an indicator, that is unreliable as the program may crash before the stream gets flushed to the screen.

Comment: Greg, please add a session scenario to the question, which produces the segfault.

Comment: @R Sahu - in the same way that there is nothing wrong with `gets`. I always wonder why people jump on `gets` but say nothing about `scanf("%s"`

Comment: gets throws a strange warning when compiling with -Wall thats why I'm not using it

Comment: Is the **first command included** in your scenario?

Comment: @RSahu I know about the weird malloc lines and threw that into my question.  I am trying to concatenate the arrays together so that I can do some comparisons later on.  At first I thought that not using malloc was the cause of the segfault but I'm finding that that isn't it.

Comment: The problem is obviously on the `strcpy(firstName, fullName);` line. `fullName` has uninitialized contents and you try to read a string out of it.  However there are so many things wrong with this program that it's like putting a band aid on a chainsaw wound

Comment: Yes and you didn't initialize it, your segfault is coming from reading past the end of it when you try to copy from `fullName` into `firstName`.

Comment: Is the first scanf not reading the extra words?  He really needs a gets to get the whole line.

Comment: Nobody "really needs a gets"

Comment: Greg, please have a look at [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: @MattMcNabb - thanks for missing the point, also he seems to crash before the strcpy.

Comment: mallocs aren't going to anything.  You are right, lots of stuff off here....

Comment: i know the mallocs are not where they need to be i will delete that from my post but that scanf statement fails to run.  any idea why?

Comment: He should put newlines in the ---> arrow prints to clarify where the segfault is actually happening.

Comment: Are you waiting for input on the second scanf, or is it all on the command line?  Did you change it to sscanf?  If not, it will still be waiting for input from the terminal.

Comment: @Greg Please include your full code in your question, or you just wast others' time.

Comment: Note that fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior and therefore also could cause your program to crash & burn.

Comment: The strcmp will fail with "append Greg r Jan 02" and "append".  So then it falls pass the conditional into something we can't see.  THAT is what is seg faulting in the first case.

Comment: whose name has 999 characters? And which month's name has 999 characters?

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc you never know what race would use your program over time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with scanf in your code. The problem is in code

```
    char fullName[2001];
    char birthday[2001];

    malloc(strlen(firstName) + 1);
    strcpy(firstName, fullName);

    malloc(strlen(lastName) + 1);
    strcpy(lastName, fullName);
    printf("%s", fullName);
```

this should be something like

```
    char fullName[2001];
    char birthday[2001];

    strcpy(fullName,firstName);
    strcat(fullName,lastName);

    printf("%s", fullName);
```

Example of working program: http://ideone.com/dvpHYL

I believe that segfault was caused by reversed arguments of `strcopy`. There probably was some arbitrary data in `fullName` (as it was not initialized before), and while trying to copy it to `firstName` (which has smaller size) data was written beyond the bounds. `malloc`s was not necessary also, but they should not cause segfaults, only memory leaks.

Comment: not sure why this wasn't working the first time.  but it seems like that solved whatever was going on. it was just so strange that the printf("---->2") wasn't showing up in the terminal

Comment: @Greg Why did you delete this code from your post and then accepted this as the correct answer? Please consider doing a rollback of the question to the previous code, or the question no longer makes any sense.

Comment: @Greg,@Jim I added some explanation about segfault.

Comment: I don't think the caused the segfault for two reasons. First char arrays are often (but not always) zeroed anyway.  Second, his strcmp error caused this code to not even be executed.

Comment: @Jim then show me what **other** errors did you found. And, about `strcmp` - sorry, but compiler thinks differently.

Comment: @Greg, the --->2 never showed up probably because there was no newline and it never flushed out.

Comment: @Ryzhehvost - look at the old code.  The strcmp would not equal 0 in his first (seg faulting) case and none of the code you cited would even be run.

Comment: @Jim it would. scanf will read the stdin upto the first whitespace, so the command would be "append". You can just run the code in debugger and see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(command,"%s %s %s %s %s\n", cmdstring, firstName, lastName, month, day);
```

Comment: I am still getting the segfault 11

Comment: That definitely does not address the problem.

Comment: Ok, after looking at the actual input, your guess are not fully wrong ;)